# if nodes have same name how to generate an array with node values under the same node name using xslt.output is in json form

Tags: xml, json, xslt

I'm new to xslt. I have to generate json using xslt taking input as xml.

Here my input xml is like this

```
<root> 
<section>   
  <item name="a">  
       <uuid>1</uuid>  
          </item> 
   </section> 
 <section>    
 <item name="b">     
     <uuid>2</uuid>  
   </item> 
     </section> 
   </root>
```

using xslt i have to get the output like this

```
{ "root" : { "section" : { "item" :[{ "name" : "a", "uuid" : "1"},
                                    { "name" : "b", "uuid" : "2"}] }
}}
```

Here what i have to do is:

1. finding whether the child nodes  have the same name in an array
2. If they have same name generating an array containing that node values under the same  node name

The output must be json.

Comment: Right..... and what have you tried?

Comment: Why doesn't your wanted result have an array of `section`? This is what corresponds 1:1 to the provided XML document.

Comment: Did you try googling "XSLT to JSON"? I think it is too trivial discussing this task in a simple question like this.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there isn't a 1:1 mapping between an XML document and a JSON object, due to the differences in the two languages and their expressive power.

**This said, in your specific case this transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vQ">"</xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
{ "root" : { "section" :
 <xsl:apply-templates select="section[1]/*"/>
 }}
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  { "item" :
    [<xsl:text/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../*/item" mode="data"/>
     ]
   }
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item" mode="data">
   <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, &#xA;&#9;&#9; </xsl:if>
   <xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>}<xsl:text/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item/@* | item/*">
   <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select='concat($vQ, name(), $vQ, " : ", $vQ, ., $vQ)'/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <section>
        <item name="a">
            <uuid>1</uuid>
        </item>
    </section>
    <section>
        <item name="b">
            <uuid>2</uuid>
        </item>
    </section>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
{ "root" : { "section" :

  { "item" :
    [{"name" : "a", "uuid" : "1"}, 
         {"name" : "b", "uuid" : "2"}
     ]
   }

 }}
```